# RichTextBox Binding is broken when text is manually modified or cleared

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` bound to a string.

Using C# I generate a string that writes to it.

But if I want to manually change the text by clicking into the `RichTextBox` and deleting it with the backspace key, or pressing Enter to make a new line, the binding becomes broken and I can no longer programmatically write to it with the string a second time.

---

**XAML**

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbScriptView" 
             Margin="11,71,280,56" 
             Padding="10,10,10,48"
             FontSize="14" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
             RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
             Style="{DynamicResource RichTextBoxStyle}">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="{Binding ScriptView_Text, 
                                Mode=TwoWay, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

**View Model**

```
private string _ScriptView_Text;
public string ScriptView_Text
{
    get { return _ScriptView_Text; }
    set
    {
        if (_ScriptView_Text == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _ScriptView_Text = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ScriptView_Text");
    }
}
```

**C#**

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
DataContext = vm;

// Display a string in the RichTextBox

vm.ScriptView_Text = "This is a test."; // <-- This won't work if text is manually modified
```

Answer (score 1):

When you edit the RichTextBox, you alter the elements inside of the FlowDocument element. The element you have a binding on, is probably removed at some point during this editing.
Have a look at RichtTextBox.Document.Groups to see what's happening when you edit the RichTextBox.

The default RichTextBox does not really support MVVM/Binding very well. You'd want to have a binding on the Document property, but this is not supported for the default RichTextBox. 
You could have a look [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66054/A-Bindable-WPF-RichTextBox).

Or extend it yourself, something like this?:

**BindableRichTextBox class**

```
public class BindableRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Document), typeof(FlowDocument), typeof(BindableRichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnDocumentChanged));

    public new FlowDocument Document
    {
        get => (FlowDocument)GetValue(DocumentProperty);
        set => SetValue(DocumentProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnDocumentChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var rtb = (RichTextBox)obj;
        rtb.Document = args.NewValue != null ? (FlowDocument)args.NewValue : new FlowDocument();
    }   
}
```

**XAML**

```
<controls:BindableRichTextBox Document="{Binding YourFlowDocumentObject, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Then you can get the string from the FlowDocument.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: @MattMcManis Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Why you have to write this line. Please remove line after check.

```
if (_ScriptView_Text == value)
{
   return;
}
```

Comment: That's how I saw how to create the ViewModel binding. I removed it but the binding still breaks.

Comment: Is it your class inherited from NotifyProperty?